# Two setState functions in one onclick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, setstate

**I'm trying to call two functions in a single onclick, however only the first one sets the state.** Following solutions from other answers, I tried calling a single function which would then call the Add() and Del() functions, but that didn't work.

This is my code:

```
    const [obj, setObj] = useState(['door1','mc','start'])
    
    const Add = (a) => {
        var newObj = [...obj]
        a.map((i) => newObj.push(i))
        console.log(newObj)
        setObj(newObj)
        console.log(obj)
    }

    const Del = (d) => {
        const newObj = obj.filter((o) => o!=d)
        console.log(newObj)
        setObj(newObj)
    }


    return (
        <div class="main">
            {obj.includes('start') && <button className="btn1" onClick={() => {Add(['text1']);Del('start')}} >Start</button>}
            {obj.includes('text1') && <div className="text text1" onClick={() => {Del('text1');Add(['text2'])}}>I've been trapped here for hours</div>}
        </div>
    )
```

In specific, this part:

```
{obj.includes('start') && <button className="btn1" onClick={() => {Add(['text1']);Del('start')}} >Start</button>}
```

How can I set state twice in one onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was a workaround and not a direct answer to my question, but it worked. I created a new function that did both the things that the two individual function (Add() and Del()) did and then called it.

```
    const delAddObj = (d,a) => {
        console.log(d,a)
        var newObj = [...obj]
        if (d!=0) {
            newObj = obj.filter((o) => o!=d)
        }
        if (a!=0) {
            newObj.push(a)
        }
        setObj(newObj)
    }
```

It takes in two arguments, one to add and the other to delete. If I only need to add, I pass in 0 instead of the second argument and similarly for deletion.

If you have a more elegant solution, I hope you can provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `handleClick` function before the return statement, and add this function to your button's onClick, like this:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    Add(["text1"])
    Del("start")
}

<button className="btn1" onClick={handleClick}>
    Start
</button>
```

Comment: I tried this and Del() function was called but not Add(). 'start' was removed from state array but 'text1' was not added.

Comment: Maybe try with `Add("text1")` instead of `Add(["text1"])`

Comment: That throws an error because Add() function takes an array